# How to go about composing core functions, rather then using imperative style?

Tags: performance, clojure, functional-programming, lisp, idioms

I have translated this code, the snippet below, from Python to Clojure. I replaced Python's `while` construct with Clojure's `loop-recur` here. But this doesn't look idiomatic.

```clj
(loop [d 2 [n & more] (list 256)]
      (if (> n 1)
        (recur (inc d)
               (loop [x n sublist more]
                 (if (= (rem x d) 0)
                   (recur (/ x d) (conj sublist d))
                   (conj sublist x))))
        (sort more)))
```

This routine gives me `(3 3 31)`, that is prime factors of `279`. For `256`, it gives, `(2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2)`, that means, `2^8`.

Moreover, it performs worse for large values, say `987654123987546` instead of `279`; whereas Python's counterpart works like charm.

How to start composing core functions, rather then translating imperative code as is? And specifically, how to improve this bit?

Thanks.

**[Edited]**

Here is the python code, I referred above,

```
def prime_factors(n):
    factors = []
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n /= d
        d = d + 1
    return factors
```

Comment: Adeel, that seems like a pretty general question to me, about a very specific case.  It would help others to provide useful suggestions if you explained what the routine is supposed to do.  It could help you as well to spell out in detail what the routine is supposed to do--not what this code does in detail, but rather, what the code is supposed to accomplish, in the abstract.  Then you can go looking for pieces of code and functions that will help do that.  Or you can ask questions about how to start writing code that would do that.

Comment: @Mars: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated it to include a brief explanation and output.

Comment: Would you post the original python code for reference?

Comment: @DominicKexel: Posted the original Python function.

Comment: see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Prime_decomposition#Clojure `(factors 279) ;; (31 3 3)`

Comment: Thanks edbond, so nice of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight translation of the Python code in Clojure would be:

```clj
(defn prime-factors [n]
  (let [n       (atom n)  ;; The Python code makes use of mutability which
        factors (atom []) ;; isn't idiomatic in Clojure, but can be emulated
        d       (atom 2)] ;; using atoms
    (loop []
      (when (< 1 @n)
        (loop []
          (when (== (rem @n @d) 0)
            (swap! factors conj @d)
            (swap! n quot @d)
            (recur)))
        (swap! d inc)
        (recur)))
    @factors))

(prime-factors 279)                    ;; => [3 3 31]
(prime-factors 987654123987546)        ;; => [2 3 41 14389 279022459]
(time (prime-factors 987654123987546)) ;; "Elapsed time: 13993.984 msecs"
                                       ;; same performance on my machine
                                       ;; as the Rosetta Code solution
```

---

You can improve this code to make it more idiomatic:

- from nested loops to a single loop:

```clj
    (loop []
      (cond
        (<= @n 1)            @factors
        (not= (rem @n @d) 0) (do (swap! d inc)
                                 (recur))
        :else                (do (swap! factors conj @d)
                                 (swap! n quot @d)
                                 (recur))))))
```

- get rid of the atoms:

```clj
    (defn prime-factors [n]
      (loop [n       n
             factors []
             d       2]
        (cond
          (<= n 1)           factors
          (not= (rem n d) 0) (recur n factors (inc d))
          :else              (recur (quot n d) (conj factors d) d))))
```

- replace `== 0` by `zero?`:

```clj
          (not (zero? (rem n d))) (recur n factors (inc d))
```

You can also overhaul it completely to make a lazy version of it:

```clj
(defn prime-factors [n]
  ((fn step [n d]
     (lazy-seq 
       (when (< 1 n)
         (cond
           (zero? (rem n d)) (cons d (step (quot n d) d))
           :else             (recur n (inc d)))))
   n 2))
```

---

I planned to have a section on optimization here, but I'm no specialist. The only thing I can say is that you can trivially make this code faster by interrupting the loop when `d` is greater than the square root of `n`:

```clj
    (defn prime-factors [n]
      (if (< 1 n)
        (loop [n       n
               factors []
               d       2]
          (let [q (quot n d)]
            (cond
              (< q d)           (conj factors n)
              (zero? (rem n d)) (recur q (conj factors d) d)
              :else             (recur n factors (inc d)))))
        []))

    (time (prime-factors 987654123987546)) ;; "Elapsed time: 7.124 msecs"
```

Comment: Thanks, Omiel. I'll definitely try this -- not having the environment now. Btw, the optimisation you suggested, was in my mind too, but fortunately and surprisingly, I came across this number `60085147514` with prime factors, `(2 7 17 23 10976461)`, the last of it is clearly greater than the square root of `60085147514`. Which means, for a number in order to be a composite there must be at least one prime below the square root of that number. But that doesn't mean that there will not be any prime divisor greater.

Comment: No, of course. Prime numbers are a trivial example. But if the divisor at hand is greater than the square root of the remaining quotient, you know for sure this quotient is prime, because you divided by all smaller prime factors before (and none of the bigger will divide it).

Comment: O' I got what you mean. Very sound, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Not every loop unrolls cleanly into an elegant "functional" decomposition.

The Rosetta Code solution suggested by @edbond is pretty simple and concise; I would say it's idiomatic since no obvious "functional" solution is apparent.  That solution runs noticeably faster on my machine than your Python version for `987654123987546`.

More generally, if you're looking to expand your understanding of functional idioms, Bedra and Halloway's "Programming Clojure" (pp.90-95) presents an excellent comparison of different versions of the Fibonacci sequence, using `loop`, lazy seqs, and an elegant "functional" version.  Chouser and Fogus's "Joy of Clojure" (MEAP version) also has a nice section on function composition.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, JohnJ. I have "Programming Clojure", but I think I started tinkering with Clojure a little too early.